# How to set the same properties to a factor level that is present in two different dataframes for illustrative purposes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two dataframes of different nature (`df1` and `df2`). However, both share one common column (`ID`) which is categorical with five levels.

When I make a plot with each one of these dataframes I get different colours for the `ID` levels, what is annoying since I need to compare the `ID`s between plots, and it would be very helpful to have the same colour for both.

Is there a way to establish levels in that column in a way that when I use `ggplot2` I get the same colours assigned to each `ID`?

Below I share a fake example. In this example the colour coincide between plots for the same `ID`s, however, in my real case it does not coincide. I do not know why now. Is there some way to correct that?

```
df1 <- data.frame(Var.1=c(90,87,34,35),
                  Var.2=c("Day","Night","Day","Night"),
                  ID=c("A","B","C","D"))

df2 <- data.frame(Var.1=c(24,34,67,78),
                  Var.2=c("Day","Night","Day","Night"),
                  ID=c("C","D","A","B"))


P.1<- ggplot(df1, aes(x=Var.2, y=Var.1,group=ID,colour=ID)) + 
  geom_point(position=pd,size=4) + 
  theme(legend.position = "top")
P.1

P.2<- ggplot(df2, aes(x=Var.2, y=Var.1,group=ID,colour=ID)) + 
  geom_point(position=pd,size=4) + 
  theme(legend.position = "top")
P.2

arrange1 <- ggarrange(P.1,P.2,nrow = 1,ncol = 2, align = c("hv"),common.legend = TRUE)
arrange1
```

[image]

Comment: Use `+ scale_color_discrete(limits = c('A', 'B', 'C, 'D'))`? It's hard to say without an example that does reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks! It worked!